# Self hosted WCF service global object appears to be newly created every time an endpoint is invoked

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, service

Following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service) I'm self hosting a WCF service inside of a windows service. My WCF service contains a global object that I update at regular intervals. I want to serialize that object to JSON and return that JSON string via a service endpoint. When I access the endpoint that calls the serialize method on the service, I get what appears to be a brand new instance of the global. The service is set to `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`

I'm instantiating in the same way as the tutorial:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyWindowsService: ServiceBase
{public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

    public Service()
    {
        ServiceName = "MyService";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new MyWindowsService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService));
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
```

And my WCF service looks like this:

```
public class MyWCFService: IWCFService
{
    private myObject = mySerializableObject;

    public MyWCFService()
    {
        myObject = new MySerializableObject();
        myObject.Init();
    }

    public Stream GetJSON()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MySerializableObject));

        ser.WriteObject(stream, myObject);

        string jsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());


        byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return new MemoryStream(resultBytes);
    }
}
```

If I `GET` the GetJSON endpoint, the string returned is a brand new initialization of the object. If I break on the GetJSON method, myObject shows all newly initialized values. Placing a breakpoint in the MySerializableObject update code shows that the updates are occurring correctly and being saved to the object in memory.

Running the same code in a normal console application works fine. Why the discrepancy? Am I handling the global incorrectly?

Comment: From the console application, are you starting the service?  Normally service get started automatically when the machine starts.  So I'm not sure why you need to start the service in the c# application.

Comment: I'm using the console app to debug the non-service code independently. The service is currently set to manual startup.

Comment: Try using a sniffer and compare the console application with the c# app. Check http header to see if they are the same.  One suspicion is the console is using a cookie while the c# is not using the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out ... I had a couple of issues going on.

1. As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292738/self-hosted-wcf-service-global-object-appears-to-be-newly-created-every-time-an?noredirect=1#comment95408087_54292738), my InstanceContextMode declaration
   wasn't decorating the right service, so it was still running in the
   default per-call context - hence, a new state object on every connection.
2. [O'Reilly](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-wcf-services/9781449382476/ch04s04.html) showed me that I wasn't creating my singleton
   instance correctly. Side note, when creating a ServiceHost using an instance, you can specify a base URI either explicitly in the constructor or in App.config. That caused me some confusion as many of the examples I ran across passed it in the constructor rather than the config.

Here's my working implementation for posterity:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my.super.original.namespace")]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet]
    Stream GetJSON();
}

//Decorator goes on WCF service, not the Windows service
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class MyWCFService : IWCFService
{
    private StateObject _myStateObject;

    public MyWCFService()
    {
        _myStateObject = new StateObject();
        _myStateObject.Init();
    }

    public Stream GetJSON()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        return "JSON String Here";
    }
}

public class MyWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    private readonly MyWcfService _wcfSingleton;

    public MyWindowsService()
    {
        ServiceName = "WindowsServiceNameHere";
        _wcfSingleton = new MyWCFService();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new MyWindowsService());
    }

    // Start the Windows service.
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        //load WCF Singleton Instance and open it for connections
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_wcfSingleton);
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```